# Why does reading shapefile from PostgreSQL database give Error reading OID from table ...?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcgis-10.1, postgresql, query-layer

I'm using arcgis 10.1 and i have a connection to a PostgreSQL 9.3 database. When i try to load a shapefile using the add query layer I get an error when opening the attribute table. The error says "Error reading OID from table. Reading rows has been stopped. Check that the datasource is valid. OID mapped column has null values. the operation is not supported by this implementation". I know there is a field that is causing this issue yet i don't know which one is or how to go solve it. Has anyone come across to the same issue?

Comment: Please detail the process you are using to add the query layer.  There are a couple of spots where the process of adding the layer sometimes selects more than one column as a unique identifier.  This may be what you are running up against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is advice in the **[Online Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000000m000000)** that may help:

> Since the value in the unique identifier field uniquely identifies a
>   row or feature object within ArcGIS, values in that field must always
>   be unique and not null. It is your responsibility to guarantee that
>   values in this field meet this requirement.

The same error has been discussed on the **[Esri Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/28657-ArcGIS-10-Error-loading-postgis-layer)**.