# GDB layer not loading properly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, layers, attribute-table, file-geodatabase

Working in v10.3, I have a .gdb with two layers; a point layer and an annotation layer. The dataset was handed to me a few days ago, and I have been editing and adding points to the point layer daily. But now, the layer doesn't load properly; all data point seem to plot on the map, but the attribute table is only showing 59 of 82 records, I get an error message when I add a definition query ("Error reading OID from table. Reading rows has been stopped. Check that the datasource is valid."). Did I break it?

I tried bringing the layer into a blank map and exporting all the data points to another layer.

Comment: This [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84070/why-does-reading-shapefile-from-postgresql-database-give-error-reading-oid-from) may lead you on the right path.

Comment: Unfortunately, your file (not personal) geodatabase may be corrupt.

Comment: Vince, if this is the case and my file is corrupt, is there a way to export the data and create a new file? Although there are records missing when I view the attribute table, the points still plot and the associated annotation still works.